# Running a Beanshell pre-processor once in a test plan

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have a Bean shell preprocessor which ends up setting up some global variables like host name and the path according to the value that the user passes.

The variables that the bean shell sets would be used by all the thread group.

Currently i've placed my BS pre-processor outside a thread and it runs perfectly..
[image]

The issue is that **it runs for every thread which isn't performance friendly**.

I just **want it to run once** at the start of the Test plan to improve performance.

I tried to put it into a setUp thread but it doesn't work.

Is there something other that the BS-preprocessor that i can use which would be performance effective(**which runs only once for the entire plan rather than for every thread**).

Answer (score 4):

1. You can put it under [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and use the following condition:

   ```
   ${__BeanShell(vars.getIteration() == 1)} && ${__threadNum} == 1
   ```
2. You can use [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) which is designed for executing pre-test actions but in that case change all occurrences of `vars.put()` to `props.put()` as JMeter variables scope is limited to current thread group only and Properties are global for the whole JVM instance. See [How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) guide for additional information

Comment: Thanks for that. Ended up with the 2nd option. Had to do some debug and  some modifications to the thread but ended up getting what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter SetUp thread group and TearDown thread group are meant for exactly this. These threads run at the start and the end of test plan. So, just add Setup thread group and add beanshells into. See links for more information:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group

In the other hand, vars are limited for each thread groups. Use props to put a value which is shared with all thread groups.

Comment: As mentioned already: SetUp Thread Groups are launched again and again, once for each "normal Thread Group, intended for the testing".

The question is about "running the SetUp Thread Group just once, for all test". So reconsider your answer please.

Comment: Take a look at jmeter definition: a test plan is group of test (including thread groups). So the last statement means running an script before all test sampler not each test sampler.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...  Just configure a User Defined Variable called firstTimeIndicator and set the value to 1

```
String firstTimeIndicator = "";
firstTimeIndicator = vars.get("firstTimeIndicator");
if (firstTimeIndicator.equals("1")) {
    log.info("The code inside the if statement executes once per test run...");
     firstTimeIndicator = "0";
     vars.put("firstTimeIndicator",firstTimeIndicator);
     }
log.info("The code after the if statement executes once per thread");
```